SwiftUI - Accessibility set focus on navigation title
I'm trying to set the VoiceOver focus to be on the navigation title when the user first opens a page. I've done this with UIKit using the UIAccessibility post(notification:argument:) function, but unsure how to accomplish this with SwiftUI.
What I've tried to do is make a custom ToolbarContent struct so that I can add the .accessibilityFocused view modifier to the title itself. However this does not seem to actually give it focus. My fear is that because it's a ToolbarContent struct and not a standard View struct, it's causing some issues.
Here's my code for the ToolbarContent, and in an effort to make it more reusable I've also added a ViewModifier for that:
struct EnhancedTitleView: ToolbarContent {
    let title: String
    @AccessibilityFocusState var isTitleFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
            VStack {
                Text(title)
                    .accessibilityFocused($isTitleFocused) // NOTE: this does not work
            }
            .task {
                 isTitleFocused = true
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EnhancedTitleViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    let title: String

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content
            .toolbar {
                EnhancedTitleView(title: title)
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func enhancedNavigationTitle(_ title: String) -> some View {
        return modifier(EnhancedTitleViewModifier(title: title))
    }
}

And ideally it can be used like this in a normal view:
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Testing")
        }
        .enhancedNavigationTitle("Testing View")
    }
}

Any help would be appreciated

I think you need to user                     .accessibilityFocused($isTitleFocused) // NOTE: this does not work
this line. Not to use $ sign before state variable

@Shivbaba'sson that's a compilation error: Cannot convert value 'isTitleFocused' of type 'Bool' to expected type 'AccessibilityFocusState<Bool>.Binding', use wrapper instead
